# how to store values of same index of 5 different arraylist in one single arraylist of size 5?

Tags: java, arraylist

i have a txt file in which i have detail of students scoring marks in 5 subjects. now i have to display the detail of each subject indivdually like for subject Maths:Max= 81 Scored by William,2 Students Failed so this what result should look like. please help me with this i am a bit new to java

i am trying to create a arraylist acc to subjects like for maths and trying to store value of marks stored by each student in maths in that arraylist..but i am not able to that.

```
public class ResultsPart2 {

 public void processLine(String data){
          String [] Martha=[25,45,6,9,87];
         String[] williams=[88,99,65,74,25];
          String[] monty=[22,45,78,85,65];

         String s="";
         int[] maths=new int[len]; 


          for(int i=1;i<len;i++){
              /// stuck over here
          }

  }}
```

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you. As in: describe the format your lines have, and what exactly your problem is. We have no idea how your file looks like, or what exact output you want to create, depending on that input.

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? If so, please post the task you've been given, because parallel arrays are probably the wrong approach unless that's what you've been asked to do.

Answer (score -1):

If you want get solution for-

> to display the detail of each subject individually like for subject Maths:Max= 81 Scored by William.

Then Below snippet code will help you..

```
public void processLine(String data){
    int[] Martha={25,45,6,9,87};
    int[] williams={88,99,65,74,25};
    int[] monty={22,45,78,85,65};

    String s="";

    ArrayList<Integer> maxInSubject = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=0;i<Martha.length;i++){
        maxInSubject.add(findMax(Martha[i],williams[i],monty[i]));
    }
    for (int i=0;i<maxInSubject.size();i++){
        for (int j : Martha){
            if (j == maxInSubject.get(i)){
                System.out.println("Sub"+i+":Max="+ maxInSubject.get(i)+" Scored by Martha");
            }
        }
        for (int j : williams){
            if (j == maxInSubject.get(i)){
                System.out.println("Sub"+i+":Max="+ maxInSubject.get(i)+" Scored by Williams");
            }
        }
        for (int j : monty){
            if (j == maxInSubject.get(i)){
                System.out.println("Sub"+i+":Max="+ maxInSubject.get(i)+" Scored by Monty");
            }
        }
    }
}

public int findMax(int a, int b, int c){
    if (a>b){
        if (a>c)
            return a;
        else
            return c;
    }
    else{
        if (b>c)
            return b;
        else
            return c;
    }
}
```